# python get current variables of the caller function

Tags: python, dir

```
def foo():
    a = 1
    b = 2
    dir() # prints [a, b]
    bar(?) 

der bar(foo_pointer):
    print dir(foo_pointer) # should print [a,b]
```

I was trying to use
`bar(sys.modules[__name__].main)`, but that gives not `[a,b]`, but `['__call__','__class__' ...]` without `a` and `b`.

I actually want to safe that pointer to use later, so i can't just pass the `[a,b]`.

Comment: Python has no pointers. What, exactly, are you trying to achieve here? You can always pass `a` and `b` to `bar`, and store references to the same values elsewhere.

Answer (score 10):

Use the [`sys._getframe()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys._getframe) to get access to the calling frame. Frame objects have a `f_locals` attribute giving you access to the local variables of that frame:

```
import sys

def bar():
    caller = sys._getframe(1)
    print caller.f_locals
```

Comment: It is important to note the warning that this function bears: `CPython implementation detail: This function should be used for internal and specialized purposes only. It is not guaranteed to exist in all implementations of Python.`

Comment: @InbarRose: which is why I linked to it directly and not to the `inspect.getcurrentframe()` synonym..